# Cart update in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

have a form like this. This is an update form, i just need to update qty foreach product in cart. 
But i have tried to explode each results and not work... it return object2array conversion error... its the first time that i get this error How i can save this in DB?

```
<form action="update">
  @foreach($products as $product)
<input type="text" name="products[]">
<input type="text" name="qty[]">
@endforeach
<input type="submit" calss="btn btn-primary">
```

This is my controller:

```
Route::post('aggiorna', function() {
$quantita = Input::all();
$carrelli = \App\Models\Carrello::where('entry_by', \Session::get('uid'))->get();
     $quantita = explode(',', $quantita);
     $i = 0;
     foreach($carrelli as $carrello) {
        $carrello->quantita = $quantita[$i]; 
        $i = $i++;
     }
    return Redirect::to('carrello'); 

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're passing a `value` attribute to the `qty[]` field! It doesn't seems to me according to the given code!

Comment: Of course value is there...

Comment: On which part of the code are you getting the error, is it inside the `view` or its inside your `controller`, if its inside any of these then on which line?

Comment: got it probably also in controller Input::get need to be name[]

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you do the iteration for each `$carreli` that exist on your database, however you never save the value.

```
Route::post('aggiorna', function() {
     $quantita = Input::all();
     $carrelli = \App\Models\Carrello::where('entry_by', \Session::get('uid'))->get();
     $quantita = explode(',', $quantita);
     $i = 0;
     foreach($carrelli as $carrello) {
        $carrello->quantita = $quantita[$i]; 
        $i = $i++;
        $carrelo->save();
     }
    return Redirect::to('carrello'); 

});
```

add the **`$carrelo->save();`** after you update the value in order to save it on db.

Also careful when you use `Input::all();`. That means that your data array contains both products and quantities. I would suggest using the following code:

```
Route::post('aggiorna', function() {
     $quantita = Input::get('qty');
     $products = Input::get('products');
     $carrelli = \App\Models\Carrello::where('entry_by', \Session::get('uid'))->get();
     $quantita = explode(',', $quantita);
     $products = explode(',', $products);
     $i = 0;
     foreach($carrelli as $carrello) {
        $carrello->quantita = $quantita[$i]; 
        $carrello->products = $products[$i]; 
        $i = $i++;
        $carrelo->save();
     }
    return Redirect::to('carrello'); 

});
```

However since i do not know what you are trying to achieve, I posted both solutions here.